# Начало работы с opencv под windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

Добрый день.

Хочу обрабатывать изображение с веб-камеры и распознавать лица людей. В связи с этим есть пара вопросов.

1. С каким разрешением лучше использовать веб-камеру? Стоит ли покупать камеру с разрешением 1280х720 или для начала хватит 640х480?
2. Слышал, что opencv работает не со всеми моделями камер, так ли это? И если так, то какие модели камер предпочтительнее?

Спасибо.

Comment: ИМХО, в данном вопросе камера - второе дело. Для написания и тестирования софта вполне подойдут видеофайлы

Answer (score 2):

Большинство вэбкамер имеют VGA-сенсор, так как HD тупо не помещается в скорость шины USB 2.0. 
Есть вэбки с сенсором VGA, но с аппроксимацией пикселов до HD (делается на стороне драйвера) - такое HD чуть менее чем маркетинговый ход, потому что никакого увеличения качества распознавания от этого не получите. 
Есть вэбки с матрицей 1M, но со сжатием изображения - это лучше чем аппроксимация, но учитывая цену на камеры и конкуренцию никто нормальный чип сжатия туда не поставит, значит опять же выигрыш по качеству распознавания будет так себе.

OpenCV поддерживает все камеры, которые подключаются как устройства V4L

Требованию по разрешению зависят от фокусного расстояния камеры, качества сенсора и максимального расстояния,  на котором требуется устойчивое распознавание. На 1м любой вэбки будет достаточно, на 2м - большинство будут работать. Если нужно больше - нужно брать либо длиннофокусную оптику, либо увеличивать разрешение кадров (но это сразу увеличит требования к вычислительной мощности)

Чтобы сделать что-то нормальное - лучше всего взять RasPI и родную камеру. Та камера в сравнении с вэбками - примерно как ракета с телегой, подключается правильно (MIPI CSI).